# Adding a library to a netbeans gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

I have decided to try and use libgdx for graphics.  However it uses gradle to manage the package; I however have very little experience with gradle.

My question is, if I have a library (.jar file) of my code.  Normally in netbeans I can right click 'libraries' and choose 'add jar/folder' and it adds the library to my ant file and more importantly the ide now recognizes the .jar and exposes it to the auto-complete etc.

On gradle I have only gotten the file to show up in the 'dependencies' branch by putting the following in the build:

`dependencies {
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}`

However the libraries won't import, nor does the ide recognize their existence.  The (absurdly large) online documentation for gradle seems to only want to deal with repositories and I can not find documentation for netbeans gradle. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem, Edward?

Answer (score 3):

This one stumped me for a while as well...

First manually add the dependency to your build.gradle script. Like your example:

```
dependencies {
   runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Then, in Netbeans's "Projects" side-panel, right click on the project name and select "Reload project" from the context menu.

Your dependencies should then show up under the project's Dependencies folder, and code completion, compile error checking, etc. should work as usual.

If you cannot see the "Projects" side-panel click select from the menu bar Window -> Projects or press Ctrl + 1.

Comment: Reload project??? really???I've been learning Gradle for a few days now and I had resigned myself to the idea of having to work with a code that worked and built but was full of error-flagged `import`s and no javadoc autocompletion whatsoever. And then you come along with "Reload project"!!! I feel like such a fool! I don't even need to add libs manually now!! Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: One must first create the folder called libs in the main project then click on Files tab adjacent to the Project tab on the left panel to view it and add jar files to it in Netbeans 18. Then in the build.gradle[project] they have the following; dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

Answer (score 2):

In netbeans 11 it looks like the reload project option has been moved to right-clicking on 'Configurations' in the projects root folder and selecting 'Download Sources'